# How to locate dynamically changing image in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, dynamic, webdriver, element

I have been asked to automate the code for an online shopping website, for adding an item to cart and checkout, but I am stuck in between.

The image of the item changes constantly and so its  xpath. I am using Actions to perform mouse over functions but it is not working and is giving an error

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 50 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: html/body/

Please find the code below:

```
w.get("http://www.provogue.com/new-arrivals");
WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(w,30);
Actions action = new Actions(w);
WebElement elem = w.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[2]/div[2]/a[1]/div/img[1]"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[2]/div[2]/a[1]/div/img[1]")));
action.moveToElement(elem).click();
action.build().perform();
```

Comment: Have you tried other ways of identifying the element? A more generalized one - `driver.findElement(By.tagName("img"));` or probably using an id or class or cssSelector? If you can post your html it'll be helpful too.

Comment: please can you share html code and present what/where exactly change?

Comment: That is a scary long XPath. Did you hand craft that or get it from Firebug, etc? As others have said, please post some HTML.

Comment: `<img width="239" height="239" title="" alt="" src="http://www.provogue.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/239x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/0/103700_rude_blue-05.jpg" style="display: none;">`

Comment: Sir , I have shared the html code of the image above.

Comment: http://www.provogue.com/new-arrivals-> refer this url , it is the second item of the first row that i want to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locator used in the above code is incorrect.To click on the second item in the first row and add it to the cart use the below code

```
         driver.get("http://www.provogue.com/new-arrivals");

         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

         //click on the first row ul[1] second item li[2] 

         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='category-products']/ul[1]/li[2]/div[2]/a/img")).click();

         //wait for the iframe to load and then switch to it

         WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30000);
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt((By
                         .className("fancybox-iframe"))));

         //select size and then

         //click on Add to cart button

         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Add to Cart']")).click();

         //switch back to default content

         driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

**EDIT**

```
   driver.get("http://www.provogue.com/new-arrivals");

     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

     //click on the first row ul[1] second item li[2] 

     Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
     WebElement productImage = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='category-products']/ul[1]/li[2]/div[2]/a[@class='product-image']"));
     actions.moveToElement(productImage).perform();
     WebElement ViewLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='category-products']/ul[1]/li[2]/div[2]/a[@class='fancybox']"));
     actions.moveToElement(ViewLink);
     actions.click();
     actions.perform();
     //wait for the iframe to load and then switch to it

     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30000);
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt((By
                     .className("fancybox-iframe"))));

     //select size and then

     //click on Add to cart button

     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Add to Cart']")).click();

     //switch back to default content

         driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```

I have tested the above code it works fine

Hope this helps you..Kindly check and get back if u hav any queries

Comment: I tried the above code, but is doing only mouse hover action on the item and not clicking it. Though i am not getting any error.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 421 milliseconds`

Comment: @Shruti I have edited my above answer used actions class.Kindly check and get back..

Comment: That's still a very long XPath, I foresee problems in the future when the markup changes slightly...